# Getting error with npm install, can anyone please guide

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, package.json

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tsnode - Not found

Comment: What's the command you executed? `npm install ...`
And where did you execute it (what directory is your terminal pointing to?)

Answer (score 2):

There is no package called `tsnode`

Try `npm i ts-node`